# Battlemind Daily and Utility Powers

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind

I have a question with D&D 4E battleminds. I'm looking for a chart that has how many utilities and daily disciplines one has access to at each level. I can't find it anywhere. Does this mean the character has access to them all?

Comment: What do you mean by 'access'? Do you mean have available at a given level as their daily/utility power for that level, or something else?

Comment: yeah, I didn't know if the class was able to use all of them available at a particular level. I wasn't seeing a battlemind table for utilities and dailies. Someone replied that they pick those up at the same levels as everyone else does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Battlemind gains powers as per the **Character Advancement Chart** (PHB pg. 29). However, it does stray from the chart at certain levels as denoted in this section:

**Psionic Augmentation**

> **At-Will Attack Powers:** At 1st level, you choose two at-will attack powers and one daily attack power from your class, but you don't start with any encounter attack powers from your class. You can instead augment you class at-will attack powers using power points. These powers have the augmentable keyword. **You gain new at-will encounter powers from this class, instead of new encounter attack powers, as you increase in level.** *At 3rd level, you choose a new at-will attack power from this class. At 7th, 13th, 17th, 23rd, and 27th level, you can replace one of your at-will attack powers with another one of your level or lower. Both powers must be augmentable and from this class.* (PHB3 pg 43).

In short- You gain Daily and Utility powers at the same level/rate as any other class (reference the chart in the 1st PHB), but you replace your Encounter Attack powers with At-Will Augmentable Attack powers. At level 1 you start of with 2 of these at-will powers, at 3rd level you gain another, and then at every other odd level you can replace one of these 3 at-will attack powers with a new one instead of gaining a new Encounter attack power.

Comment: Thanks so much. My group was a bit confused and that cleared it up perfectly.